# Redirecting bash output

Tags: bash

I'm having a little trouble with a script I am running.  I cannot get output redirected when the script is successful. I need to just pass it to /dev/null as I really don't care about it.

```
if ! p4 -p 1667 -c prefetch -Zproxyload sync //bob/...; then
    printf "\nFailed to Sync //bob \n\n" &> $OUTPUT_LOG
else &>/dev/null
fi
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `&>` isn't a separate command that you can abstract away from the call to `p4`; it's part of the syntax of a command invocation.

Answer (score 3):

You have to decide what you want to do with the output before you generate it — before you run the command.  If you want the output preserved to go in the log file when there's a problem, but to discard it when there is no problem, you will need to save the output, decide whether there was a problem, and then deal with it.

Saving the output (standard output and standard error) means either putting it in a file or in a variable.  Here, a variable is probably appropriate.

```
output=$(p4 -p 1667 -c prefetch -Zproxyload sync //bob/...  2>&1)
if [ $? != 0 ]
then
    {
    echo "$output"
    printf "\nFailed to Sync //bob\n\n"
    } > $OUTPUT_LOG
fi
```

The alternative, using files, might be better if the output can be extremely copious, but it is more complex to make sure that the files are properly named (see `mktemp`) and much more complex to make sure that the files are properly removed even if the script is interrupted (see `trap`).